# BookshelfJS - How to create/insert model with related model?

Tags: node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I know this is something super basic, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Maybe my Google-fu just sucks. I have users and timelines, and I want to associate a timeline with its creating user when the timeline is created. I can't find the best way to make this association happen. I either can't access the ID attribute or it's not set by the time the timeline is being created. I don't want to nest the timeline creation within a then on saving the user, since I'll be doing a bunch of complicated relationships among several different objects. Here's what I have so far:

Models:

```
var Timeline = bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'timelines',

  creator: function() {
    console.log("timeline model creator function called");
    return this.belongsTo(User);
  }

}, {
});

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'users',

  timelines: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Timeline);
  },
}, {});
```

Instantion:

```
var user3 = new User({
  username: 'user3',
  email: 'email3@example.com',
  password: 'password1'
}).save();

var timeline3 = new Timeline({
    name: 'timeline3',
    creator: user3,
    start_date: '1900-01-01 00:00:00',
    end_date: '1950-01-01 23:59:59',
    time_scale: 1
}).save();
```

It looks like user3 is a promise instead of the model instance, as I get an error stating the given value to creator is not a valid integer. It has the attributes isFulfilled and isRejected.

How do I save/insert a new model instance with its relationship to another model instance?

Comment: You have to nest them but you should put everything in a transaction and use the transacting option on each save/fetch so that if one throws an error the whole transaction rolls back